# After entering UserName/Password FTP server is not responding?

Tags: virtual-machine, ftp, iis, windows-server, azure

I have set up a Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 R2. I have also setup IIS 8.5 FTP server there. When I access the site using localhost url in the same server, I will get UserName/Password prompt and when I enter UserName/Password, I get the successful response. But if I access the same site using DNS name(*.cloupapp.net) from the same server or from a remote machine then I will get the UserName/Password prompt but when when I enter UserName/Password and click Log on button then the server not respond, the browser loads infinitely.

Here is FileZilla Log,

```
Status: Resolving address of XXX.cloudapp.net
Status: Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER XXX
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS **************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (100,73,170,123,193,12).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: To Access FTP server, multiple TCP ports are used: TCP 21 will be used to send commands (incl. Login) to FTP server, while additional ports are used to retrieve data and directory list from FTP server. You must configure the firewall to allow all the connections used by FTP.

Comment: @user3767013 OK Please let me know the other ports?

Comment: Please check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421710%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for detailed information.

Comment: Not working. Please see the update and fileZilla log.

Comment: The TCP Connection to your server 100.73.170.123:xxxx failed to establish. Try disable Windows Firewall completely for a short time to see whether it is the Windows Firewall blocking the incoming Connection, or your Hoster has additional firewalls.

Comment: @user3767013 Windows Firewall is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Goto settings of filezilla.

change the FTP setting.

instead of passive mode -- select active mode and click ok.

try now it will work.

azure doesn't allow passive ftp, thats the head scratching thing here.